# variance of the sprt stopping time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sequential-analysis, stopping-time

Is it possible to reduce the *variance* of the average stopping time of a fixed boundary SPRT by allowing variable boundaries as the test progresses at the price of increasing the average stopping time? If yes, is there a specific distribution for which the boundary sequence is known to have the smallest variance?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen ok, but which question? I looked for similar ones but was unable to find any. I would like to learn, please help by pointing out at least a related one; and thank you for  your help.

Comment: Well, this was closed because YOU asked the same question twice! and this one copy was closed. Have a look through the tag [tag:sequential-analysis] but unfortunately there does not seem to be much activity there

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "allowing variable boundaries," given that the SPRT already uses boundaries that change over time?  Indeed, what do you mean by a "fixed boundary" SPRT?  Note, too, there is a trivial solution: take a sample of fixed size.  The variance of the stopping time is zero.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The Math site should not have migrated the question, because they were explicitly told it had been asked here.  I therefore sent the migrated version back to them and reopened this version.

Comment: @whuber: OK, seems like a good solution.

Comment: @whuber I meant by "fixed boundaries" the scheme I learned when used it in radar detection; with conventional notation given $\alpha$, $\beta$ set $A \approx  (1-\beta)/\alpha$ and $B \approx \beta/(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: Please bear in mind these are *slopes* of *variable* boundary curves.  Regardless, the existence of trivial solutions to your question indicates you haven't asked it in a form that is likely to generate meaningful answers: you need to provide more information or details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @whuber John Tukey: "Far better an approximate answer to the right question, which is often vague, than an exact answer to the wrong question, which can always be made precise." Of course, I if really knew how to ask the right question I might be able to find the answer in a book myself but I have not and I cannot; anyhow I remove the question. Thank you for reviewing it.

Comment: We have here been using the comments in an effort to identify what the "right question" might possibly be.  That is a two-way exercise: you have to be willing to respond constructively to requests for clarification or context before we can hope to give even an approximate answer.  Otherwise, we risk giving good answers to a misunderstood question and that is bad for everyone.

Comment: @whuber I completely agree with you. The sad part for me is that besides your two comments in this thread my question "generated" exactly zero interest that tells me that I need to study *more* statistics before I could ask anything remotely resembling to be intelligent at this forum.

Comment: I think that might be misreading the situation.  There's an art to writing interesting questions and much of that has nothing to do with statistics.  I do not claim to be a master of that art, or any good at it at all, but I have found some success in emulating well-received questions (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes) and answers (https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer).  Clearly there's an element of luck: some topics are popular and others are not well known; SPRT is among the latter.